# Mocking PHP functions - naming conventions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

What are the best practices for creating method names when writing OOP that will be mocking native PHP functions?

Example: an object needs to use file_put_contents(), and I want to mock that, so I'm thinking the right approach is to wrap file_put_contents() in a class method.  But what's a good way to name the methods?  I was thinking maybe *wrap_file_put_contents()* but is there a better standard for things like this?  Thanx!

Comment: Maybe you should use something like [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/)?

Comment: also give http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2015/01/mocking-php.html a read! =] http://php.net/uopz is great for mocking native functions

Comment: You could take advantage of namespaces and define the functions to be mocked in the same namespace as the object which is calling them. You can see an article about this technique at [matthew weier o'phinney's blog](https://mwop.net/blog/2014-08-11-testing-output-generating-code.html) (the lead developer of ZF). It may be impractical if you have to test many classes but give it a though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't rename them. That would just be horrific. For the function you appear to be trying to test [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/) would allow you to test wihtout hitting the disk and so have fast unit tests, and so you probably don't need mocking for it.

For other things you can use a hack to make a mock version of the function without affecting the legibility of the code you're testing, while only being very slightly horrific.

By declaring a function with the same name as the function you want to mock, but in the namespace of the function/method where it is being used, the namespace version of the function would be used in preference to the PHP version.

File SomeNamespace\MockHeader.php:

```
namespace SomeNamespace;

$headersSet = [];

class MockHeader {
    static function load();
}

function header($string, $replace = true, $http_response_code = null) {
    global $headersSet;
    $headersSet[] = [
       'string' => $string,
       'replace' => $replace,
       'http_response_code' => $http_response_code
    ];
}
```

File SomeNamespace\TestClass.php:

```
namespace SomeNamespace;

class TestClass {
    function foo() {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    }
}
```

By calling SomeNamespace\MockHeader::load() in the unit test, the header replacement function would be loaded, and would be used in preference to the \header function that PHP provides.

You can also use Uopz as described by the [author of that extension](http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2015/01/mocking-php.html), to replace functions programmatically, as opposed to hackily. But either method is preferable to renaming things imo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a preferred solution has already been found, however I was having some fun with this, so I thought I'd throw this version without namespacing into the code cosmos for fun purposes.

It'll fall back to the SPL functions gracefully, and its extendable. They can be nested with minimal effort if you wanted to set some defaults in Std.

Lastly, some sort of instance control over the get_defined_functions() out could potentially make sense, I'm not sure what overhead the repeated calls is:

```
<?php

class Std
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        $stdFuncs = &get_defined_functions()['internal'];
        if (in_array($name, $stdFuncs))
        {
            return (method_exists($this, $name))
                ? call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args)
                : call_user_func_array($name, $args);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args)
    {
        $stdFuncs = &get_defined_functions()['internal'];
        if(in_array($name, $stdFuncs))
        {
            return (method_exists(get_called_class(), $name))
            ? call_user_func_array(array(get_called_class(), $name), $args)
            : call_user_func_array($name, $args);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Test extends Std
{
    public static function strlen($string)
    {
        return trim(strlen($string));
    }
}

// Test it
$x = new Test();
echo $x->strlen("test") . PHP_EOL;
echo $x->intval("test") . PHP_EOL;
echo Test::strlen("test") . PHP_EOL;
echo Test::intval("test") . PHP_EOL;
```